# How to use Java lambdas to collect elements in a list of a new type?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I've been struggling reading the javadocs to determine how to use lambdas to elegantly combine a list of rows of one type into a grouped-up list of another type.

I've figured out how to use the `Collectors.groupingBy` syntax to get the data into a `Map<String, List<String>>` but since the results will be used in a variety of later function calls... I'd ideally like to have these reduced to a list of objects which contain the new mapping.

Here are my data types, `RowData` is the source...  I want to get the data combined into a list of `CodesToBrands`:

```
class RowData {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public RowData() {

    }

    public RowData(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class CodeToBrands {
    private String code;
    private List<String> brands = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public List<String> getBrands() {
        return brands;
    }

    public void addBrands(List<String> brands) {
        this.brands.addAll(brands);
    }

    public void addBrand(String brand) {
        this.brands.add(brand);
    }
}
```

Here's the test I'm writing to try and figure it out...

```
@Test
public void testMappingRows() {
    List<RowData> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    rows.add(new RowData("A", "Foo"));
    rows.add(new RowData("B", "Foo"));
    rows.add(new RowData("A", "Bar"));
    rows.add(new RowData("B", "Zoo"));
    rows.add(new RowData("C", "Elf"));

    // Groups a list of elements to a Map<String, List<String>>
    System.out.println("\nMapping the codes to a list of brands");
    Map<String, List<String>> result = rows.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RowData::getId, Collectors.mapping(RowData::getName, Collectors.toList())));

    // Show results are grouped nicely
    result.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> {
        System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey());
        entry.getValue().forEach((value) -> System.out.println("..Value: " + value));
    });

    /**Prints:
     * Mapping the codes to a list of brands
        Key: A
        ..Value: Foo
        ..Value: Bar
        Key: B
        ..Value: Foo
        ..Value: Zoo
        Key: C
        ..Value: Elf*/

    // How to get these as a List<CodeToBrand> objects where each CodeToBrand objects to avoid working with a Map<String, List<String>>?
    List<CodeToBrands> resultsAsNewType;
}
```

Can anyone provide any help in trying to get this same overall result in a easier-to-use datatype?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've got to call new to create a CodeToBrands somewhere.  I don't seen any ctor in that class, so you're going to have issues.

Comment: If I made the constructor for `CodeToBrands(String code, List<String> brands)`, could I do this all in one stage using the `rows.stream().collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)` method?  My curiosity is whether I can skip the middle `groupingBy` stage with the `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: @duffymo it already has a default constructor, and you could use a lambda statement block which should enable one to call `setCode` and `addBrands` as shown in my answer.

Comment: I would prefer a constructor that initialized the object correctly instead of default with setters.

Comment: @duffymo Right, I see. that's what you meant by your comment ;) .

Comment: Your solution is correct and works. I think a single crow call is more concise b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it in one pass using [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
Collection<CodeToBrands> values = rows.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        RowData::getId,
        rowData -> {
            CodeToBrands codeToBrands = new CodeToBrands();
            codeToBrands.setCode(rowData.getId());
            codeToBrands.addBrand(row.getName());
            return codeToBrands;
        },
        (left, right) -> {
            left.addBrands(right.getBrands());
            return left;
        }))
    .values();
```

Then, if you need a `List` instead of a `Collection`, simply do:

```
List<CodeToBrands> result = new ArrayList<>(values);
```

---

The code above could be simplified if you had a specific constructor and a merge method in the `CodeToBrands` class:

```
public CodeToBrands(String code, String brand) {
    this.code = code;
    this.brands.add(brand);
}

public CodeToBrands merge(CodeToBrands another) {
    this.brands.addAll(another.getBrands());
    return this;
}
```

Then, simply do:

```
Collection<CodeToBrands> values = rows.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        RowData::getId,
        rowData -> new CodeToBrands(rowData.getId(), rowData.getName()),
        CodeToBrands::merge))
    .values();
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was hoping for (but wasn't sure if it was possible).  Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks also for providing the constructor.... I had been trying it with the signature `CodeToBrands(String code, List<String> brands)` instead of just `String brands`... don't know how long it would've taken me to correct that

Answer (score 4):

You can simply chain further operations after grouping and collect the result like so:

```
List<CodeToBrands> resultSet = rows.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RowData::getId,
                        Collectors.mapping(RowData::getName, Collectors.toList())))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> {
                     CodeToBrands codeToBrand = new CodeToBrands();
                     codeToBrand.setCode(e.getKey());
                     codeToBrand.addBrands(e.getValue());
                     return codeToBrand;
                 }).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

This approach creates a stream over the `entrySet` after grouping and then simply maps each `Map.Entry<String, List<String>>` into a `CodeToBrands` instance and then finally we accumulate the elements into a list implementation.

Another approach would be using the `toMap` collector:

```
List<CodeToBrands> resultSet = rows.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(RowData::getId,
                 valueMapper -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(valueMapper.getName())),
                 (v, v1) -> {
                     v.addAll(v1);
                     return v;
                 })).entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(e -> {
                        CodeToBrands codeToBrand = new CodeToBrands();
                        codeToBrand.setCode(e.getKey());
                        codeToBrand.addBrands(e.getValue());
                        return codeToBrand;
                }).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

This approach is quite similar to the above but just "another" way to go about it. So, this specific overload of the `toMap` collector takes a key mapper (`RowData::getId` in this case) which produces the keys for the map.

The function `valueMapper -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(valueMapper.getName()))` is the value mapper which produces the map values.

Finally, the function `(v, v1) -> {...}` is the merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key.

The following chained functions are the same as the first example shown.

Comment: Thanks, this no doubt works.  I was wondering if it's possible to `collect()` the data in one operation without the `groupingBy` stage which first loads everything into a map.  I was playing with the `rows.stream().collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)` method... but wasn't sure if that was even possible...

Comment: @Cuga I can't see a way doing it with that. the solutions shown is the simplest I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do it is creating a constructor in `CodeToBrands` using its fields:

```
public CodeToBrands(String code, List<String> brands) {
    this.code = code;
    this.brands = brands;
}
```

Then simply [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) each entry to a new `CodeToBrands` instance:

```
List<CodeToBrands> resultsAsNewType = result
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> new CodeToBrands(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  I figured I could stream the entrySet after it was in the map. This works and is great.  Do you know if it's possible to do it all in 1 stage? By this I mean going straight from the `List<RowData>` straight to the `List<CodeToBrands>` with some kind of collector or reducer without needing the `Map<String, List<String>>` in-between?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers seem to be keen on first creating the original map you already have, then creating `CodeToBrands` in a second go.

IIUC, you wanted this in one go, which you can do by creating your own `Collector`. All it needs to do is collect into your target class directly, instead of creating a list first.

```
// the target map
Supplier<Map<String,CodeToBrands>> supplier = HashMap::new;

// for each id, you want to reuse an existing CodeToBrands,
// or create a new one if we don't have one already
BiConsumer<Map<String,CodeToBrands>,RowData> accumulator = (map, rd) -> {
    // this assumes a CodeToBrands(String id) constructor
    CodeToBrands ctb = map.computeIfAbsent(rd.getId(), CodeToBrands::new);
    ctb.addBrand(rd.getName());
};

// to complete the collector, we need to be able to combine two CodeToBrands objects
BinaryOperator<Map<String,CodeToBrands>> combiner = (map1, map2) -> {
    // add all map2 entries to map1
    for (Entry<String,CodeToBrands> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
        map1.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), (ctb1, ctb2) -> {
            // add all ctb2 brands to ctb1 and continue collecting in there
            ctb1.addBrands(ctb2.getBrands());
            return ctb1;
        });
    }
    return map1;
};

// now, you have everything, use these for a new Collector
Collector<RowData,?,Map<String,CodeToBrands>> collector =
    Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner);

// let's give it a go
System.out.println("\nMapping the codes by new collector");
Map<String,CodeToBrands> map = rows.stream().collect(collector);
map.forEach((s, ctb) -> {
    System.out.println("Key: " + s);
    ctb.getBrands().forEach((value) -> System.out.println("..Value: " + value));
});
```

Now if you insist on having a `List` instead, maybe do `new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet())`, or `collectingAndThen()`; but in my experience, you might as well use the `Set` it returns for almost all use cases.

You can boil down the code by using the lambdas directly, but I figured it be easier to follow to do it step by step.

Comment: This is excellent!  I especially appreciate the way you separated out the steps since a large part of this was for me to learn/understand so I can re-use the pattern in other areas.  The supplier/accumulator/combiner params to `collect()` had been twisting my brain around